# Inject Javacode on runtime into deployed (Vaadin-)Application

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin

We are using Tomcat to deploy our Vaadin-Application. No problems there. 
What we would like to do, though, is to execute java-code without redeploying our application. For example: we would like to give the end-user the possibility to add code to our program. So every time a button is pressed the end-user code gets executed as well. (e.g. add extra logging functionality, inform a different user via mail….).

It would also be fine, if the end-user could only use certain classes/methods. e.g.:

`this.sendMail(“abc@yxz.com”)`

Is this possible? I would appreciate it if anyone could give me a starting point where to look.

Thanks in advance,
Stephanie

Comment: Not sure if it's a good idea in the first place. Who's going to test code that's going to be executed? How to protect the application from malicious code injection?

Comment: The end-user who would be allowed to “add” code has to be in a certain group/role. And that’s also why I would like to provide only a certain amount of classes/methods and functions… e.g. sendMail() or log()…

Comment: then add user interface controls which are going to enable/disable these operations

Comment: I do not think that will work, since in the long run the end-user should also be able to implement basic logic operations based on their input. E.g.: if "field_a" ISNOT NULL then do something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a look at [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/).  This is used in a number of IDEs to add code in running programs.